# azure ad b2c auth in web app not showing social options

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have enabled two **identity providers** i.e: facebook and google in my **azure ad b2c** tenant, but when I test them from within the portal with **Run Now** on the signup sign-in policy, only email option shows up, I've also tried and linked it up with my web app **.NET CORE 2.0** app and there as well only email option shows up.

I followed official docs to create and save identity providers in my tenant, please let me know if there is an extra step which I don't know about. Following is a link to google + identity config
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app

Comment: Ensure that you have config the social identity data provider in the policy that you used to login. Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies).

Comment: please provide this as an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have config the social identity data provider in the policy that you used to login. Refer the link below:

[Azure Active Directory B2C: Built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies)